Subgrouping before final grouping
I have SQL query where I subgroup 4 items before final grouping. Here is the SQL query :
 Select DISCIP, 
                SUM(TOTAL) as TOTAL,
                SUM(COMP) as DONE,
                SUM(REM) as REM
 from (
            select
              case when Discipline in ('ELECTRICAL','F&G','INSTRUMENTATION','TELECOM','HVAC') then 'E&I'
                   when Discipline in ('PIPING') then 'PIPING'
                   when Discipline in ('EQUIPMENT') then 'EQUIPMENT'
                   when Discipline in ('MECHANICAL COMPLETION') then 'MC'
    
                   else 'OTHERS' end as DISCIP,
          
                    Count(TagNo) as TOTAL,
                    Count(case when  Completed=1 then 1 else null end) as COMP,
                    Count(case when  (Completed!=1 or Completed is null) then 1 else null end) as REM
            
           from 
                com.WBS
                where (NA=0 or NA IS NULL)
           group by Discipline)t
    
    group by t.DISCIP

Here I subgroup 'ELECTRICAL','F&G','INSTRUMENTATION','TELECOM','HVAC' into E&I before final grouping. I can't figure out how to do the same in Linq.
Here is the result:


It will help if you demonstrate what you have so far, and what specific part of the code, in Linq, you are struggling to translate here.

I don't think the pregrouping is needed, but could be wrong?

Please never just post SQL and ask for conversion. At least show a class model so navigation properties and the multiplicity of associations are visible. Also, tell which ORM is involved (Entity Framework?), and show your own first efforts so we see where specifically you need help. The best LINQ query is hardly ever a 1:1 reproduction of a SQL query.

One of the first steps in translating SQL to LINQ is to Translate subselects as separately declared variables. So I'd first declare t as a variable and then use t within your final LINQ.   var t = from ...  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786

And please don't use images for data, use table markdown

If you want the double grouping (and I'd suspect with the right indexing it's probably more efficient to use it) then you can still do so. Just use .GroupBy.Select twice.
await db.WBS
    .Where(w => w.NA == 0 || w.NA == null)
    .GroupBy(w => w.Discipline)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        g.Key,
        TOTAL = g.Count(),
        DONE = g.Count(w => w.Completed == 1),
        REM = g.Count(w => w.Completed != 1 || w.Completed == null)
    })
    .GroupBy(s => s.Key switch
    {
        "ELECTRICAL" or "F&G" or "INSTRUMENTATION" or "TELECOM" or "HVAC" => "E&I",
        "PIPING" => "PIPING",
        "EQUIPMENT" => "EQUIPMENT",
        "MECHANICAL COMPLETION" => "MC",
        _ => "OTHERS"
    })
    .Select(g => new
    {
        DISCIP = g.Key,
        TOTAL = g.Sum(s => s.TOTAL),
        DONE = g.Sum(s => s.DONE),
        REM = g.Sum(w => s.REM)
    })
    .ToListAsync();

If you are on an old version of C# and don't want to upgrade for some strange reason, then you can replace the switch with more long-winded ?: expressions.
    .GroupBy(s =>
        s.Key == "ELECTRICAL" || s.Key == "F&G" || s.Key == "INSTRUMENTATION" || s.Key == "TELECOM" || s.Key == "HVAC"
        ? "E&I"
        : s.Key == "PIPING"
          ? "PIPING"
          : s.Key == "EQUIPMENT"
            ? "EQUIPMENT"
            : s.Key == "MECHANICAL COMPLETION"
              ? "MC",
              :"OTHERS"
    )


i get this error :  CS8370 Feature 'or pattern' is not available in C# 7.3. Please use language version 9.0 or greater.

OK see edits. The switch expression is also not supported in that case. But I recommend you upgrade.

Assuming that you have the content of the table in an appropriate collection that map exactly the column on the db you can do:
    .Where(w => w.NA == 0 || w.NA == null)
    .GroupBy(w => w.Discipline switch
    {
        "ELECTRICAL" or "F&G" or "INSTRUMENTATION" or "TELECOM" or "HVAC" => "E&I",
        "PIPING" => "PIPING",
        "EQUIPMENT" => "EQUIPMENT",
        "MECHANICAL COMPLETION" => "MC",
        _ => "OTHERS"
    })
    .Select(g => new
    {
        DISCIP = g.Key,
        TOTAL = g.Count(),
        DONE = g.Count(w => w.Completed == 1),
        REM = g.Count(w => w.Completed != 1 || w.Completed == null)
    })
    .ToList();

i think you don't need the double grouping. Also since we don't know your columns type, you should double check for nullable values.
Also note that, the switch statement as it is, probably only works in .Net8
EDIT:
in case you have a lower version of .NET, change the group by
.GroupBy(w => 
{
    string discipline;
    if (new[] { "ELECTRICAL", "F&G", "INSTRUMENTATION", "TELECOM", "HVAC" }.Contains(w.Discipline))
    {
        discipline = "E&I";
    }
    else if (w.Discipline == "PIPING")
    {
        discipline = "PIPING";
    }
    else if (w.Discipline == "EQUIPMENT")
    {
        discipline = "EQUIPMENT";
    }
    else if (w.Discipline == "MECHANICAL COMPLETION")
    {
        discipline = "MC";
    }
    else
    {
        discipline = "OTHERS";
    }
    return discipline;
})


I would counter that the double grouping is probably more efficient, as it allows the server to narrow down the resultset using indexes, before doing the final grouping which can't use indexes (because of the CASE)

@Charlieface i mean, without knowing really the detail of how big is this table, i always prioritize the code readability. Unless there are some serious heavy lifting you have to do on your backend, i prefer shorter instructions. However the query can be easily modified in case of need

@Daniele Sartori i get this error :  CS8370 Feature 'or pattern' is not available in C# 7.3. Please use language version 9.0 or greater.

@Hussein check the edit
